# How to set my column at the center of the chart with ShinobiCharts

Tags: iphone, ios, graph, charts

I have this column chart that has 2 modes, monthly visualization and yearly visualization, the monthly visualization works just fine with many column, however, my yearly visualization is broken because i can't get the only column that appears to be on the center of the chart, it's always being set to the first point on my XAxis.

If I were using a NumberAxis it would be easy to solve, just set the column to the middle point (in this case, position 6 among the total of 12 months). However I'm using CategoryAxis, since it isn't ordered as NumberAxis is, I'm unable to use the same solution....

How can I achieve this result with a CategoryAxis ?

PS: No matter the SChartRange I set to this Axis, the column will always be set to the first position in the XAxis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to achieve the result I wanted.

I've altered the range to be around the first dataPoint only, this way the column got placed  in the middle of the chart without having to be the "middle dataPoint", being the ONLY dataPoint. The code goes into my  sChart: dataPointAtIndex forSeriesAtIndex as follows

```
-(id<SChartData>)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart dataPointAtIndex:(int)dataIndex forSeriesAtIndex:(int)seriesIndex{

.
.
.
    SChartNumberRange * numberRange;
    if(isYearlyChart){
            numberRange = [[SChartNumberRange alloc] initWithMinimum:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-0.9]andMaximum:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(1)]];


    }
```

The normal NumberRange I was using was from 1 through 13.

Hope this helps others with similar problems regarding this subject :)

PS: I'll mark this as the correct answer as soon as possible.